# Validation directive that takes a function - a good idea?

Tags: validation, angular

**Context:** I'm adding validation to my form heavy Angular 2 app, which uses the [Template-Driven forms](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-template-driven-forms) approach. This means I need to write Directives for custom validation rules.

While some validators are fairly common and can be reused across components(a date value is before another date value), there are inevitably "one-off" validations that are specific only to certain components. Creating a custom validation directive for each of these seems like overkill.

**Question:**
I came up with a directive that takes a `ValidatorFn` (code below). This allows to specify validation functions in component classes and reuse the directive across components. This seems to work fine, but I have a bad feeling that this was "too easy" - there must be a reason why this is not built into Angular 2 Forms module.

Does anyone know a reason why such a directive is a good / bad idea?

**Directive Code:**

```
export const FUNCTION_VALIDATOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => FunctionValidator),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[validationFn][formControlName],[validationFn][formControl],[validationFn][ngModel]',
  providers: [FUNCTION_VALIDATOR],
  host: {'[attr.validationFn]': 'validationFn ? validationFn : null'}
})
export class FunctionValidator implements Validator, OnChanges {
  private validator: ValidatorFn;
  private onChange: () => void;

  @Input() validationFn: ValidatorFn;

  private createValidator() { this.validator = this.validationFn; }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['validationFn']) {
      this.createValidator();
      if (this.onChange) this.onChange();
    }
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.validator ? this.validator(c) : null;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: () => void) { this.onChange = fn; }
}
```